# How close do multiples of 3 different unit fractions sum to 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am wondering how to solve or make advance in the following problem.
Given 3 different unit fractions, i.e. $\frac1{n_i}$ for $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$, and gcd($n_i,n_j$)=1. Hence no multiples of two or three of these numbers sum to 1.

I want to add multiples of at least two of these three numbers such that their sum is less than 1 but as close as possible. So I want $$\frac1{n_1} k_1 + \frac1{n_2} k_2 + \frac1{n_3} k_3\text{  for }k_i<n_i,\ k_i\in\mathbb{N}$$ to be as close as possible to 1 and I want to know how close it can get.

Ist there any way to determine a upper bound on how close they sum to 1?

I am sure this is possible by enumerating all possibilities and always solving a linear diophantine equation for 3 numbers but this is inefficient and I was more thinking about properties on the size of the smallest $\frac1{n_i}$.
I was thinking that one of the numbers must be very small in order for a possible sum to be very close to 1. Is there any way to make this precise?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: A trivial lower bound for the error is $1/n_1n_2n_3$. I don't know, when this bound can be achieved.

Comment: It may be somewhat related to Frobenius coin problem.

Comment: I have checked this and in my opinion it doesn't help more than the fact that one can solve efficiently a linear diophantine equation with three numbers. Although I don't know if there is any closed form of the possible solutions for this?!

Comment: For example $\frac 12+\frac13+\frac17=\frac{41}{42}$

Comment: @Jyrki: How do you get your bound from the first comment? This does give me a bound as I wished but I am still hoping to get a more precise one.

Comment: Isn't the denominator of the sum a factor of $n_1n_2n_3$? If the sum is $<1$, it is then $\le 1-(1/n_1n_2n_3)$, no?

Comment: But, yeah. The coin problem probably isn't very useful here, because the coins are relatively large in comparison to the target sum.

Comment: Thanks. Well no, as I know it you can choose the size of the coins.

Answer (score 4):

There are infinitely many cases where Jyrki's lower bound $1/(n_1 n_2 n_3)$ is achieved.  Consider for example

$$ \frac{m-1}{2m-1} + \frac{1}{2m} + \frac{m}{2m+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{(2m-1)(2m)(2m+1)}$$

EDIT: Another example:

$$ {\frac {m}{8\,m+1}}+{\frac {2\,m+1}{8\,m+3}}+{\frac {5\,m+3}{8\,m+5}}=
1-{\frac {1}{ \left( 8\,m+1 \right)  \left( 8\,m+3 \right)  \left( 8\,
m+5 \right) }}
$$